# Ошибка adoquery1 cannot perform this operation on closed dataset

Tags: delphi, ado

Есть форма1 в которой таблица из базы данных (access)(в базе данных четыре таблицы). Подцепленная к базе данных через ADOConnection1 При нажатии кнопки "Добавить" выскакивает форма2 где я задаю данные в таблицу с помощью DBedit и DBCombobox через ADOquery1 и Datasource1. И все работает, но я добавил напротив комбобокса еще одну кнопу которая открывает форму3 в которой еще одна таблица из этой же базы данных, где по принципу сделанно все также как и форме1. Adoquery2 и Datasource2 лежат форме3, там же есть еще один ADOconnection1.
Теперь если я запускаю программу открывается форма1 и при нажатии кнопки добавить он пишет сабж. Что сделал не так?

Код формы1:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
Form2.show;  
Adoquery1.insert;  
end;  
procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
form2.show;  
end;  
procedure TForm1.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
Adoquery1.delete;  
end;
```

Код формы2:

```
procedure TForm2.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
Form1.ADOquaery1.edit;  
close;  
end;  
procedure TForm2.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
Form2.close;  
end;  
procedure TForm2.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject); *кнопка добавить*  
begin  
Form3.show;
end;
```

Код формы3:

```
procedure TForm3.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
Form4.show;
Form3.ADOquery1.insert;
end;
procedure TForm3.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
form4.show;
end;
procedure TForm3.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin  
form3.adoquery1.delete;  
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отформатируйте код правильно, а то читать невозможно.

У вас, скорее всего, не подключен **ADOConnection**. Вы делаете ему **ADOConnection := true**?

Comment: Пока ждал ответ уже разобрался с этим спасибо. Теперь проблема в следующем. При открывании второй таблицы нажимаю кнопку "добавить" и вылезает форма4 где нужно ввести данные во вторую таблицу. Данные ввожу нажимаю ок но данных в таблице нету. код на кнопку Form3.ADOquery1.edit;
close;
Почему данные незаписываются?